# How to avoid creating new translation records by updating those that exist?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization, unique, globalize

I am using Ruby on Rails 4 and the [Globalize](https://github.com/globalize/globalize) gem.

When I submit multiple translations from a form in my application, Globalize creates a new record for each locale in the translation database table, even if the translation for the given locale already exists in that table.

I would like to have *one translation per locale* so when the form is submitted then a new translation record is created only if it doesn't exist yet, otherwise it should be just updated with the submitting data.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer this question without more information about the format of data in the form.

Assuming you have all the locales in `I18n.available_locales`, and you are updating an attribute `title`, something like this will work (assuming your record is called `post`):

```
I18n.available_locales.each do |locale|
  post.translation_for(locale).title ||= ...
end
post.save!
```

I can provide more specific guidance if you provide more info.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20268557/how-and-where-to-handle-the-updating-process-of-associated-records) can help you to help me...